# Flutter ios error when run app: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, sharedpreferences

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/t_/d4qsnct51tvftvp8_gx0smlw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.IV7Tnt/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir98238e/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/messages.g.m:7:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'permission_handler_apple' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'network_info_plus' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'geolocator_apple' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'Starscream' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'Sodium' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
/Users/user/Documents/fixValidation/mobile_sahla_chauffeur/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'PusherSwiftWithEncryption' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
/var/folders/t_/d4qsnct51tvftvp8_gx0smlw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.IV7Tnt/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir98238e/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Comment: Can you tell us which flutter sdk version you are using with which macos and Xcode ?

Comment: All is up to date

Comment: Xcode. 13.4.1
Flutter: 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your Flutter and iOS project by firing those commands in terminal at your project directory.

1. `flutter clean` this will clean flutter project for you.
2. `cd ios && pod deintegrate` this will clean iOS project for you.
3. Delete `Podfile.lock` and `pods` directory, this will remove all dependencies in your iOS project.
4. Go back to root of your project by firing this command `cd..`, run `flutter pub get`.
5. go to iOS directory (`cd ios`) and fire pod install.

This will clean your iOS and Flutter apps and you might be able to fix your issue.

Comment: Samme error still happens